# Exercise 0.19 in Miles Reid's Commutative Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

I have the following exercise in Miles Reid's *Undergraduate Commutative Algebra*:

> **Exercise 0.19** Study the ring $B=\Bbb Z[\sqrt 5]$. A maximal ideal $P$ of $B$ lies over a prime $(p)=P\cap\Bbb Z$ of $\Bbb Z$. If $p\neq 2,5$ then either
>
> 1. $5$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, and then $p$ factors in $B$ as $p=f_1f_2$, and $$B/(f_1)\cong B/(f_2)\cong \Bbb F_p$$ so that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are prime elements of $B$; or
> 2. $5$ is a quadratic non-residue mod $p$, and then $$B/(p)\cong\Bbb F_p[\sqrt 5]$$ is a quadratic field extension of $\Bbb F_p$, so that $p$ remains a prime element in $B$.

I would like to know if my solution works, and it there is a shorter, and more clever, proof of any of the parts.

**1)** If $5$ is quadratic residue then we will show that $p$ is reducible.
Let $g^2\equiv_p 5$, then by Quadratic Reciprocity we know that $p\equiv_5 \pm 1$. Consider the set $$S=\{x+gy\mid 0\leq x,y\leq\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor\}\subset\Bbb Z$$
There are $(1+\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor)^2>p$ different tuples $(x,y)$, which means that there are two different tuples $(x,y), (x_0,y_0)$ such that $$x+gy\equiv_p x_0+gy_0\\(x-x_0)^2\equiv_p 5(y-y_0)^2$$ Now let $r=x-x_0$ and $s=y-y_0$, then the last line gives that $p$ divides $|r^2-5s^2|$. Since also $0<r^2,s^2<p$ we have that $$|r^2-5s^2|=Np\tag{1}$$ with $N=1,2,3,4$.

- $N=1$, $|r^2-5s^2|=p$ and we have what we want.
- $N=2,3$ is impossible. To see this note that $|r^2-5s^2|\equiv_5 1\equiv_5 \pm N$
- $N=4$. Reduce $|r^2-5s^2|=4p$ modulo $4$ to obtain $r^2\equiv_4 s^2$, therefore $r,s$ have the same parity. If both $r,s$ are even then we get $$\left|\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)^2-5\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)^2\right|=p$$ which is what we want. If $r,s$ are both odd then either $4\mid r+s$ or $4\mid r-s$. This gives two different factorization we can use to cancel the $4$:

1. If $r+s\equiv_4 0$ we have $$4\left|\left(\frac{r+s}{4}\right)^2-5\left(\frac{r+5s}{4}\right)^2\right|=4p\\\left|\left(r+6s\right)^2-5s^2\right|=p$$
2. If $r-s\equiv_4 0$ we have $$4\left|\left(\frac{r-s}{4}\right)^2-5\left(\frac{r-5s}{4}\right)^2\right|=4p\\\left|\left(r-6s\right)^2-5s^2\right|=p$$

In either case we can write $p=|a^2-5b^2|$, and factorize it over $B$ as $p=u(a+b\sqrt 5)(a-b\sqrt 5)$, where $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ and $u\in B^\times$. Write $p=\alpha\beta$, with $\alpha,\beta\in B$, and define $N(a+b\sqrt{5})=|a^2-5b^2|$. Then we have:

- $N(\alpha)>0$
- $N(\alpha\beta)=N(\alpha)N(\beta)$
- $N(\alpha)=1\iff\alpha\in B^\times$

$p^2=N(p)=N(\alpha)N(\beta)$. If either $N(\alpha), N(\beta)=1$ then $p$ would remain prime, therefore $N(\alpha)=N(\beta)=p$, and so both $\alpha,\beta$ are themselves primes. Consider $B/(f_i)$, where $i=1,2$. We have the isomorphism $$\phi:\Bbb Z/\ker(\phi)\rightarrow B/(f_i)$$ where $\ker(\phi)=(f_i)\cap\Bbb Z=(f_i \overline{f_i})=(p)$ so that $$B/(f_i)\cong\Bbb F_p$$

**2)** Suppose $5$ is a quadratic non-residue mod $p$. Let $p=\alpha\beta$ with $\alpha,\beta\in B$. Then $p^2=|a^2-5b^2||c^2-5d^2|$, and wihout loss of generality we can assume $$a^2\equiv_p 5b^2$$ But then $b$ can't have a multiplicative inverse, otherwise $(ab^{-1})^2\equiv_p 5$ and hence $5$ would be a quadratic residue. We must therefore have that $p\mid a,b\Rightarrow p^2\mid a^2,b^2$. This yields $$1=\left|\frac{a}{p}\pm\frac{b}{p}\sqrt 5\right|$$ Therefore $b=0$, and so $a=\pm p$. Thus $p$ remains prime in $B$.

Comment: Careful in the proof of 1: $p$ could be *not prime* but still *irreducible*, since $B$ is not really “nice” as a ring.

Comment: @Mindlack Fixed, thank you!